# Not getting Expected O/P a list of dictonary or a dict of dict

Tags: list, dictionary, python-3.7

```
d1 = {}
l1=[]
for i in range(1,3):
    d1["t"] = i
    print(d1)
    l1.append(d1)
    print("")
print("------------------------------------------------")
print("Final list: " + str(l1))
```

Expected 
 Final list:[{'t': 1}, {'t': 2}]

Actual Final list:[{'t': 2}, {'t': 2}]

Answer (score 0):

As dict in python is by reference the issue was resolved by declaring the dict inside the loop.